# Map must have exactly two type arguments error

Tags: apex, map

I'm writing a method in my trigger handler to see if a field has changed and then will send the record ID and user lookup id to a handler class to create a new record.

I've copied other methods in the class and adjusted where I need to however, I get the error

> map must have exactly 2 type arguments (Line: 2, Column: 5)

Here is what I have, what did I do wrong?

```
public static void createSalesParticipant(Map<Id, Opportunity> newMap, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap)
{
    Map<Opportunity> salesParticipants = new Map<Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity oppy : newMap.values())
    {
        if(oppy.Sales_Participant_1__c != null && oldMap.get(oppy.Id).Sales_Participant_1__c != oppy.Sales_Participant_1__c)
        {
            salesParticipants.add(oppy.Id, oppy.Sales_Participant_1__c);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's where you went wrong:

```
Map<Opportunity> salesParticipants = new Map<Opportunity>();
```

Maps need to have two data types, one for the Key, and one for the Value.

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> salesParticipants = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
```

It seems to me you're confusing List/Set and Map, since you're also trying to use "add"; the Map type uses "put" instead.

Finally, it seems that you're really just trying to map one Id to another, so you probably meant:

```
Map<Id, Id> salesParticipants = new Map<Id, Id>();
for(Opportunity oppy : newMap.values()) {
    if(oppy.Sales_Participant_1__c != null && oldMap.get(oppy.Id).Sales_Participant_1__c != oppy.Sales_Participant_1__c) {
        salesParticipants.put(oppy.Id, oppy.Sales_Participant_1__c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I started as a list but then it didn't like adding two ids to the list so I switched over to a map. It didn't occur to me to use id, id instead of id, opportunity. This is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Map's need two arguments  IE
`Map<string, Opportunity>` is correct
`Map<Opportunity>` is Not.

The first argument is the key that you can use to access the second argument.

For example, if I did something like

```
Map<String, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<string, Opportunity>();
oppMap.put('1st opp', opp);
```

then I could retrieve that opportunity by

```
newOpp = oppMap.get('1st opp');
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `Apex Developer Guide` on **[`Maps`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm)**:

> ## [Maps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm)
>
> A map is a collection of key-value pairs where each unique key maps to a single value. Keys and values can be any data type—primitive types, collections, sObjects, user-defined types, and built-in Apex types. For example, the following table represents a map of countries and currencies:
>
> ```
> Country (Key)     'United States'  'Japan'  'France'  'England'  'India'
> Currency (Value)  'Dollar'         'Yen'    'Euro'    'Pound'    'Rupee'
> ```
>
> Map keys and values can contain any collection, and can contain nested collections. For example, you can have a map of Integers to maps, which, in turn, map Strings to lists. Map keys can contain up to only four levels of nested collections.
>
> To declare a map, use the Map keyword followed by the data types of the key and the value within `<>` characters. For example:
>
> ```
> Map<String, String> country_currencies = new Map<String, String>();
> Map<ID, Set<String>> m = new Map<ID, Set<String>>();
> ```

If you look at these, and examine the `Maps` in your method signature, you will see that there should be two types separated by a comma within your angle brackets (`<>`). You could denote the correct way to write a `Map` type as `Map<T1, T2>`, where `T1` is the key type and `T2` is the value type. That can be a `Map<String, String>`, `Map<Id, Opportunity>`, etc. In your declaration, you only have one type specified. There is no such thing as a `Map<Opportunity>`, because either you didn't specify the key type or you didn't specify the value type.